# I want to add two textboxes together

Tags: vba, textbox

I have 2 text boxes and a label.

I want to be able to display in a label the concatenated text of the two textboxes. I have used the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Label1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)  

End Sub
```

This doesn't work, however, and I am getting

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

Can somebody explain why this is happening and how I can fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Macro enabled excel file, add the activeX version of command button, text boxes and label.

After this you can have your desired result with this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Label1.Caption = TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text
End Sub
```

Please check that the macros are saved correctly.
This solution works on Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate text in VBA use the ampersand (`&`). The `.Text` method just pulls the value. The following worked for me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Label1 = TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly I am still getting the same error when i use (&). I have also tried removing val() and still no joy :(

Comment: create a temporary value and change it to `Label1.Text = tmp` and see which line it breaks on. Then we can know if it's an issue with the reading or writing part.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why you would have the debug highlight on that line is if there is no `CommandButton1` in your form any more (perhaps renamed it?) But I created a simple example and used the code above. It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I did rename, but changed them back to default name to see it that worked. I will start over and see it if that works. cheers for the help :)

Comment: Is your code in the userform or did you move it to a module? it should be in the userform. I have my doubts, but I'm grasping for ideas as to why the above does not work for you. Maybe try a brand new form?

Comment: it appears i needed to write "label1.caption =", as demonstrated by Bujutsu

Thank you for your help, however :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Dear it Works.

txtTotal = val(me.text1) + val(me.text2)