# Adding the values from two textbox's in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

New to MS Access and had a question. I am trying to add the value from txtKits and txtFG. I want them to show up in a seperate textbox called txtTotal that returns the value (the textbox also needs to non editable). Here is what the form looks like:

[image: Click to view image]

If the user enters just one of the two calculation fields, then I get the attached output. I want it to not give that output. It can stay blank until both are entered. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to add two textboxes together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679715/i-want-to-add-two-textboxes-together)

Comment: textbox does not have a caption option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if both fields are numeric first in your calculated field:

```
=IIF(IsNumeric([Field1].Value) AND IsNumeric([Field2].Value); [Field1].Value + [Field2].Value; Null)
```

Comment: Where would I add that? I tried adding this in the code editor txt_Total.Value = IIF(IsNumeric(txt_FG.Value) AND IsNumeric(txt_Kits.Value); txt_FG.Value + txt_Kits.Value; Null)

Comment: As an expression for your calculated field, where you currently do the calculation

Comment: I am using the Control Source and if I use that, then the output doesn't do any calculation. It just shows "#Name?" now. Never returns a value.

Comment: It is saying "You omitted an operand or operator, you entered an invalid character or comma, or you entered text without surrounding it in quotation marks."

Comment: You might need to add square brackets around your field names. Try that.

Comment: Can you give an example? I have put brackets on them, and same thing. It pretty much just takes everything out after the ";"

Comment: See the current edit. Note that the `;` is your list separator, in different locales you might need to replace it with `,`. How? See [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/how-do-i-change-the-system-separator-delimiter-to/9f8d5f2c-940f-4418-b952-bfeac867c03e)

Comment: =IIf(IsNumeric([txt_Kits]) And IsNumeric([txt_FG]),[txt_FG]+[txt_Kits],Null) that is how I was able to do it. Thank you for your help. It was hard to read and decipher within the small textbox. Didn't notice the "..." button to open the editor.